# How to use pectine (E440) to make confectionary/gummy?

Tags: gelling-agents, pectin

I am experimenting with a fructose/maltodextrin/MCT powder mixture as fuel for longer running sessions. I have a good mixture which works well for me, has a nice mouth feel due to the MCT, is reasonably easy to swallow and does not give me stomach problems. But carrying it around in squeeze bottles and spilling it over myself while trying to gulp it while running is less fun. The mixture has the consistency of a thick goo.

I bought some pure pectine (made from apple if that is relevant, 100% E440) and am going to experiment with gelling my mixture, basically converting it into confectionary, so I can take it with me as-is (without a squeeze bottle) and can either bite it off, or wrap it in breakfast paper if necessary. I found lots and lots of recipes for marmalade/jelly based on pectine, but it's hard to tell which parts of those recipes are relevant for the "mechanical" working of pectine, and which are just separate concerns (i.e. food safety in the case of boiling the fruit juice...).

Wikipedia mentions that it needs to be heated - what is the relevant temperature it needs to reach to start the process (food safety concerns play no role in my application in the way they do for marmalade making)? Does it matter how fast or slow it cools down? Is it possible to freeze the end result or will that change the gelling properties after thawing?

As far as I can tell, I need to lower pH somewhat; I like my running fuel to taste sour anyways, and am using a few spritzes of lemon concentrate for taste reasons. Does pectine require some very specific acidicity for best results, or is just eyeballing it probably good enough?

While I could simply start throwing ingredients together - do you have some percentage of pectine vs. sugars vs. water that would be a good starting starting point?